# Data migrations for OneToOneField in django with data in tables already

Tags: python, django

I have a case model that I added a OntToOneField to
Example:

```
 zoho_api = models.OneToOneField(
    ZohoAPIState,
    default=create_new_zoho_api_state,
    related_name='referral_profile',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE
)
```

During development there was no data in the tables and the migration worked fine. The migration is adding the zoho_api key to the database using the following commands.

```
 python manage.py makemigrations

 python manage.py migrate
```

But trying to migrate with data in the tables gives me the following errors:
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OX6fS.png)

Says DETAIL: Key(zoho_api_id)=(some guid) is duplicated.

How do I get around this issue?

Comment: Please update the question with what migration you are doing...

Comment: Can you show `create_new_zoho_api_state`? It seems this callback is not returning unique values